# What is the best place to register notification channel?

Tags: android, push-notification

What are advantages and disadvantages of register notification channels in:

1) Application.class

2) MainActivity.class?

Which way is better and more flexible to avoid problems in future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one or more static `CHANNEL_ID`, you can register them in the `Application` without problems.

If you need to manage them in a more dynamic way like creating/removing them based on your app business logic and/or user preference, you should handle them in a more proper class like an `Activity` or a `Service`.

> Which way is better and more flexible to avoid problems in future?

You won't have problems either way. Problems will arrive only to handle different API behaviours or business logic updates and this will impact your code regardless where it is located